# ViewSwitcher as a ListView item - how to call .showNext() on correct ViewSwitcher item?

Tags: android, listview, android-layout, viewswitcher

I have a ListView with ViewSwitcher items. The goal is to tap a list item to switch between ViewSwitcher views. Tapping works as expected, but scrolling away from a tapped item and then back sometimes changes which item is displaying the second view from the ViewSwitcher.

Here is my ListView item layout, the ViewSwitcher is @+id/details:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width  = "fill_parent"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content" >

    <ViewSwitcher
        android:id                 = "@+id/details"
        android:layout_width       = "fill_parent"
        android:layout_height      = "fill_parent"
        android:measureAllChildren = "false" >

        <!-- two views I want to switch between are here -->

    </ViewSwitcher>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My Activity that finds @id/details and calls .showNext().

```
public class MyActivity extends ListActivity {
    private MySQLiteOpenHelper data;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
    private Cursor cursor;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        String[] FROM = { "_id", "_id", "name", "name" };   
        int[] TO = { R.id.my_list_id, R.id.my_list_id2, R.id.my_list_name, R.id.my_list_name_details };

        data = new MySQLiteOpenHelper(this);
        cursor = data.myList();
        startManagingCursor(cursor);

        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, cursor, FROM, TO);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        ListView list = getListView();
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id) {
                ViewSwitcher item = (ViewSwitcher) view.findViewById(R.id.details);
                item.showNext();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I *think* my problem might be that @id/details is not actually unique, so undefined behavior happens when scrolling.

If this is the case, then how can I assign a unique ID to each ViewSwitcher or find the correct ViewSwitcher to call .showNext() on?

Comment: when you scroll back to a switched ViewSwitcher? You find it unSwitched?

Comment: Yes, when I scroll back it is unswitched and a *different* item is switched.

Comment: Example: 10 items in list, tap #9, scroll up, tap #2 (can't see #9), scroll down and #9 is unswiched and #10 *is* switched. Scroll up and tap #2 again, scroll down, and #9 is backed to being switched. Strange unswitching/switching only seems to happen to ViewSwitchers outside of view in the ListView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wrong code is in

```
// Cursor/Adapter code here to populate list from SQLite DB.
```

Please post the code

However here are some **Hints**

1. Extend ArrayAdapter
2. Add an ArrayList with all the items inside
3. Keep in this ArrayList the status of each ViewSwitcher

A simple way would be to make the ArrayList an ArrayList of ViewSwitchers

Comment: I edited and added some more code. data.myList() returns a Cursor that is pulling data from a sqlite database. Is my problem with using SimpleCursorAdapter?

Comment: I extended an adapter and kept the state of the ViewSwitchers, but it was still displaying weird behavior. At that point, I just decided to manually display one of two views rather than trying to get the ViewSwitchers to behave and that worked great. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.